# Cannot order sort users on Mathematics Meta

Tags: support, users

Why can't I sort users on [Mathematics Meta user page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users) by `Month` , `Week`,`All` like on the other Stack Exchange sites ?

Is this by design or a bug ?

[image]

Should be :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Because there is no reputation on per-site metas. (This is not specific to Mathematics Meta.)